# Add up all entries of column 2 and 3 with the same name in column 1 and delete all except one

Tags: mysql

I have a table A that contains a few columns with entries. In column 1 is the campaign name which can occur more than once (in the table). In column 2 is the number of successfull delivered mails of that campaign. In column 3 is the number of clicks per campaign.

Now what I want to do: I want add up all successfull delivered mails and clicks of every campaign if the specific campaign exisits more than once, delete all double entries of campaigns which exist more than once and leave all unique campaigns as they are.

Here´s an example:

For example if the table A contained:

```
|col1                           ||col2   ||col3|
+-----+
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE         ||35     ||15 |
|20161217_LC_YoBirthdayNo_A_CH  ||100    ||10 |
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE         ||25     ||10 |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE           ||10     ||1  |
|20170117_SV_YoBirthdayYes_A_DE ||50     ||25 |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE           ||15     ||9  |
```

I want a query that will update Table A as following:

```
|col1                           ||col2   ||col3|
+-----+
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE         ||60     ||25 |
|20161217_LC_YoBirthdayNo_A_CH  ||100    ||10 |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE           ||25     ||10 |
|20170117_SV_YoBirthdayYes_A_DE ||50     ||25 |
```

This time, I´ve got no starting point how to handle this...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I do not know what to say

Comment: Do you understand that the semantics of your table before and after the "update" will be different? Not a very good starting point at all! If you had a correct data model then the solution would be much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try lik e this:

```
DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `deleteRep` $$
        CREATE PROCEDURE `deleteRep`()
        BEGIN

        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  table_temp
         select col1, sum(col2) as col2,sum(col3) as col3 from `table`
         group by col1;

         truncate `table`;
         insert into `table`
         select col1,col2,col3 table_temp;

        END $$

    DELIMITER ;
```

call procedure:

```
call `deleteRep`();
```